# Display inline in a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a big footer. I have tried my best to make the links displayed inline but I am unable to do so. Please help out. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">

#footer{
    width:auto;
    height:600px;   
    background:url(footer.png);
}

#footer div{float:left; width:43.5%}
#footer div:nth-child(2n+1){clear:none}
#footer div:nth-child(3n+1){clear:left}
#footer div li a{float:none; width:auto; display:inline; font-size:1em; padding:0; line-height:1.5em; background-color:transparent}
#footer .contribute{border:none; background-color:transparent}​​​​​

#footer div h4{transition:color 0.3s;  -moz-transition:-color 0.3s; -ms-transition:color 0.3s; -o-transition:color 0.3s; -webkit-transition:color 0.3s}

#footer div:hover h4{color:#e53b2c}

#footer div:nth-child(2n){clear:left}

#footer div{width:100%; clear:both}

#footer .contribute{background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8); border-bottom:10px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.025); background-color: transparent;
    border: medium none;}

#footer div li {display:block; width:94.5%; float:left; font-size:0.95em; }

#footer li{padding:0.125em 0}

#footer a{border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1)}

#footer a:hover{border-bottom:1px solid rgb(65,183,216)}

#footer a:active, #footer a:focus { background-color:#e53b2c; border: none; } 

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="footer">
    <div class="contribute">
        <h4>Best of Design</h4>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.smashingmagazine.com/responsive-web-design-guidelines-tutorials/">Responsive Design</a></li>

    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="contribute" >
        <h4>Best of Coding</h4>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.smashingmagazine.com/learning-javascript-essentials-guidelines-tutorials/">JavaScript &amp; jQuery</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="contribute">
        <h4>Smashing Hub</h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.smashingmagazine.com">Smashing Magazine</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="contribute">
        <h4>Other Resources</h4>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/08/to-five-smashing-years-and-a-free-anniversary-ebook-treat/">Free Anniversary eBook</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>           
</div>    
</body>​
</html>
```

Here is a visual of what design I am trying to make,
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what the design you're looking for is. Why do you have lists that only have one item? Are all 4 of your `contribute` divs supposed to be inline, or do you only want the links that are next to the `<h4>` element to be inline?

Comment: @Wex: For now I have kept only one item. I will increase the items when I am done with it. Yes all of them should be inline. I have added an image to make things clearer.

Comment: Why are you overwriting the `#footer div` property over and over in your CSS?

Comment: I am reusing the code from that site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `float: left;` instead of `display: inline;`.

The problem with your CSS is that you override the style for `#footer div` a lot:

```
#footer div{width:100%; clear:both}
```

This is one of these and its the main reason for breaking the layout.

Try to remove part of the style and refactor it to clean out a bit. You will thank us for this.

"If you can't understand your own code, its time to take a break and refactor."

Answer (score 2):

The typical way you see people accomplish this problem is by using the `float` property. Note that I added `overflow: hidden` to `#footer` to clear the floats.

```
#footer { overflow: hidden; }
.contribute {
    float: left;
    width: 25%; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/nxvdG/

If you're trying to stick with using inline, you will use similar code, only inline elements behave differently when stuck next to each other. Whitespace in your markup, ie `</div> <div>` will produce a gap between the two elements. To make it so the elements touch, you need to remove the white space in your markup, like `</div><div>`.

```
.contribute {
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/TkxKm/

Comment: You see, I already have `float:left;` in my code but that does not work.

Comment: Your CSS is incredibly messy. I would scrap what you have and try and implement the solution that I've given you; the information I've given you will solve your problem.